# Use ISO_Level3_Shift as Escape when tapped

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xcape

I use an alternative keyboard layout that uses CapsLock and # as *ISO_Level3_Shift* modifiers.

```
setxkbmap de koy
```

I also like using CapsLock as additional Escape key when it's just tapped. This can be easily reached by:

```
xcape -e "ISO_Level3_Shift=Escape"
```

But this makes both Level3 modifiers act as Escape. How can I apply xcape only to the left modifier key (labeled CapsLock)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading on the [xcape page on github](https://github.com/alols/xcape), I found the easy solution. Last year a [pull request](https://github.com/alols/xcape/pull/78) was merged that allows passing keycodes instead of keysyms to xcape.

The solution is:

```
xcape -e "#66=Escape"
```

How to get the right keycode?

```
xev -event keyboard
```

Press down the key you want to modify. Then you should see something like that:

```
KeyPress event, serial 29, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x190, subw 0x0, time 771139, (110,626), root:(204,711),
    state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 51
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

There you find your keycode (66 in this example).